# Make nginx return a JSON header

Tags: php, nginx

> PHP/5.4.45, nginx/1.2.1

My PHP script set correct content/type for json:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

But in server response header:

```
Content-Type:text/html
```

How I should change header?

Comment: Make sure you set the header before echoing anything in your php script.

Comment: @Ravi Rajendra - If I use apache it return correct header. Problem only with nginx.

Comment: try removing the closing tag ?> and do let me know if this fixes your problem.

Comment: it's not fix problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution @stdex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `application/json` to the [`charset_types`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html#charset_types) directive. Be careful to not forget one from the default one. Mine reads like this (default plus application/json)

```
charset_types text/xml text/plain text/vnd.wap.wml application/javascript application/rss+xml application/json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in `/etc/nginx/mime.types`:

```
`application/json      json;`
```

And reload nginx.

Comment: It's only set application/json header for .json files. I'm need set application/json header for content genereted by php script.